# List activity with header, footer and empty all visible

Tags: android, listview

I would like to have the listview in a ListActivity be displayed with the header and footer visible all the time even if the list data is empty.

An empty list causes the empty view to appear and the header and footer to disappear. However my header has filtering UI and should therefore always be visible.

The only way I can make it happen at the moment is if I take the header and footer out of the listview and implement them as static views outside in the activity layout. However then these are always visible and only the data scrolls.

I would prefer for both to just be on top and bottom of the scrolling list. Wrapping it all in a scroll view does not work since then there are two nested scroll views( the list view outside and the wrapping one).

Is there a way to do this nicely apart from a hack like adding a fake record?

Comment: You can set the visibility of your empty view as `GONE` and set your `ListView` visible. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798387/android-how-to-reuse-a-header-layout-as-an-empty-view-in-a-listview/10347758#10347758

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make your empty view include your header.

i.e.

```
 <ListView />
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
       // Add whatever you want here including your header
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That way the header/footer does not scroll as part of the list. I already got that like I said in the question and would prefer the header and footer to be part of the scrolling list. Wrapping a scroll view around both does not work either..

Comment: No, you add the header with addHeaderView(R.layout.your_header); And you also add the header into the id/empty. That way it scroll's when you have items, and is still shown when you don't. Make use of the <include/> and <merge/> tags to stop XML code duplication

Answer (score 14):

This answer is a bit late, but you can simply override BaseAdapter.isEmpty() to return false.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you learn something new every day, and today you taught me something new

Answer (score 3):

You could use my [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) for this. Add the header view, add the data adapter, and add the footer view. They will all scroll in unison, and the header and footer will persist even if the adapter in the middle has no rows.

Comment: and the empty view will show instead of the list view as well?

Comment: @Manfred Moser: This is covered in the `MergeAdapter` documentation on the page I linked to above. By default, `MergeAdapter` with your header+footer views will not show the empty view, even if the adapter is empty. If you wanted to change that behavior, you would need to override `isEmpty()` in a subclass.

Comment: Thanks Mark - it might be a bit heavy to add all that in my case but I will have a look - maybe I can take some of your code and use an approach from it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this workaround is a hack. But, without having to create a fake item.

For an ArrayAdapter you can add a null item... i.e.

```
myAdapter.add(null);
```

And, in the MyAdapter getView(..) you do something like:

```
myItem = getItem(position);
if (myItem == null) {
   return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_empty_row, null);
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: Adding null is not a good idea. It will fill up your items with cache/previous recycled view.

Answer (score 1):

I found that header/footer will always be visible if you don't call ListView.setEmptyView.

Instead, manually show/hide your empty view:

```
emptyView.setVisibility(list.size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue, if ListView has no item, you could ListView.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(new ArrayList())); and the header is also visible.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had both header and footer views. 
I placed my `mEmptyView` in footer view.

First, as user1034295 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23396305/1083957), I overrided adapter's `isEmpty()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
// If not overridden, then this will return `true` if your list is empty
// Thus, you won't see header/footer views
   return false;
}
```

ExpandableListView adapter's `getGroupCount()`. Override appropriate method for your adapter.

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    int size = null != mData ? mData.size() : 0;
    if (0 == size) mHostFragment.toggleEmptyView(true);
    else mHostFragment.toggleEmptyView(false);
    return size;
}
```

In you activity/fragment

```
public void toggleEmptyView(boolean show) {
    if(show && mEmptyView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else if (!show && mEmptyView.getVisibility() != View.GONE)
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

`mEmptyView` is a child in `ListView`'s footer view.
So, when your list becomes 0 sized you'll get your header/footer views remained + `mEmptyView` will become visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the listView and the empty layout together in a FrameLayout, and put 
the empty layout margin in the size of the header, then, you can change the visibility of the empty view when an item is added to listview.

layout will be as similar to this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listheader="@layout/myHeader"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/headerHeight"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/emptyLayout">

       //insert your layout here

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```