# ListView not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a layout which contains 3 `spinners`,1 `EditText`,1 `Butto` and below that button I have placed my `ListView`.The `ListView` has a header which is also not displaying. For some reason it is not showing. I have attached my xml file and the java code where I create the header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/yearSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/monthSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/daySpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amountEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:hint="@string/amount">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addproduct_button"
        android:textColor="#372c24" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

============================================

```
visibleTable = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    createTableHeader();

    private void createTableHeader() {
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    visibleTable.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
}
```

======================

this is my header xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#ff347c12">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ThirdText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/amount"
    android:width="50dip" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SecondText"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.60"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/date"
    android:width="150dip" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FirstText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:width="20dip" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ListView` is empty, then nothing is shown that's normal. For your header view to be shown even when there is no data, have a look at this question [List activity with header, footer and empty all visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449522/list-activity-with-header-footer-and-empty-all-visible)

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have added my header cml  which is what that link you gave me.but still I don't see my header

Comment: sorry,can you tell me what I need to add in my code.maybe I am getting it wrong

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should use the listview.setAdapter( ... ) method in order to set data to your listview.

Here is a nice tutorial for Listview and Adapters : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterintro

Answer (score 0):

You may add data in your spinner, like this,

```
<string-array name="displaying">
            <item >a</item>
            <item >b</item>
            <item >c</item>
        ...
</string-array>
```

so that you can show them.