# addHeaderView does not work when the list is empty

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I am using following layout(header.xml) to add header in a listview,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/greetingContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="header view"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and on the other side, i am using,

```
View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,null);
getListView().addHeaderView(header);
```

when the list is empty it's not working, stays invisible..

my question may be the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988011/android-addheaderview-disappears-when-no-items-in-listview), but unable to understand,
please help!

Comment: You can use a Relative layout have text view at the top and listview below the textview. yes it won't show when listview is empty

Comment: Everything is fine, when the list contains data!

Comment: yes it is meant to work that way by default that is how it works.

Comment: how can i set a header when the list is empty then?

Comment: read by first comment or look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127132/how-to-show-header-of-listview-when-its-empty

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution, all you need to do is that you should ALWAYS set an adapter for your `listview`, even when you do not have any data to show.

Comment: This worked for me and should probably be marked as the correct answer. Just set an `ArrayAdapter` with an empty dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar header view and it is coming fine when there is no data in the listview.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    if (listView.getHeaderViewsCount() == 0) {
        headerView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.listheader,     null);
        listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);
    }
    return view;

}
```