# Show ListView header even when ListView has no items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Since my ListView is in a ScrollView and there is a complex layout above the ListView I had to set that layout to be the header of the ListView. This made things work wonderfully, except one thing: When the ListView has no items, the header does not show up. This header is basically the base of the whole layout, the ListView includes only comments written by users.

I checked solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127132/how-to-show-header-of-listview-when-its-empty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988011/android-addheaderview-disappears-when-no-items-in-listview/5264523#5264523) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798387/android-how-to-reuse-a-header-layout-as-an-empty-view-in-a-listview/10347758#10347758) and others but I still don't know what to do.

This is how I set the header for the ListView:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bucket_profile_lv);
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bucket_profile_header,null,false);
lv.addHeaderView(header);
```

When I am downloading the data for the header, it has nothing to do with the adapter of the ListView. I refer to them as

```
num_added = response.getString("NUM_ADDED");
tv_num_added.setText(String.valueOf(num_added));
```

where

```
tv_num_added = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.bucket_profile_bucket_no_added);
```

When I am downloading the comments, I put the result (username, photo, comment etc.) in arrays and link them to an adapter:

```
if (response.length() > 10) {
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);

            for(int j=0;j<innerJsonArray.length();j++){  
                                JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                                arr_tips_id.add(jsonObject.getString("COMMENTID"));
                                arr_tips_userid.add(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                                arr_tips_username.add(jsonObject.getString("USERNAME"));
                                arr_tips_userphoto.add(jsonObject.getString("PHOTO"));
                                arr_tips_fbuserid.add(jsonObject.getString("FB_USERID"));
                                arr_tips_imagetype.add(jsonObject.getString("IMAGE_TYPE"));
                                arr_tips_twuserid.add(jsonObject.getString("TW_USERID"));
                                arr_tips_twphoto.add(jsonObject.getString("TW_PHOTO"));
                                arr_tips_tips.add(jsonObject.getString("COMMENT"));
                                arr_tips_date.add(jsonObject.getString("TIMEDIFF"));

                                myadapter = new MyAdapter(BucketProfileActivity.this, arr_tips_id, arr_tips_userid, arr_tips_username, arr_tips_userphoto, arr_tips_fbuserid, arr_tips_imagetype, arr_tips_twuserid, arr_tips_twphoto, arr_tips_tips, arr_tips_date);
                                lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
                                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    /*Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                    Toast.makeText(BucketProfileActivity.this, "3 -- " + strDate + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
         } else {
            Toast.makeText(BucketProfileActivity.this, "No comments, how to show header?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

In my adapter I have overriden isEmpty() but it didn't help:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return false;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you really initializing and setting the adapter on _each iteration_ of your JSON array structures?!

Comment: Hi! What do you mean? I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean why did you put the adapter initialization code _inside_ your inner for loop?

Comment: Thanks, what a mistake :) However, I am still looking for a solution

Comment: If you initialize and set the adapter even when there are no results, then the header should show up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use addHeaderView. Instead make the header as a separate item

```
<LinearLayout
  ...
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <include layout="@layout/bucket_profile_header" />

  <ListView
     .....
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Like I said, I have the whole thing in a ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your adapter once, for example when you inflate your views in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` and also set your adapter to your listview (after you added your headerView).

In your JSON iteration loop do something like this:

```
myadapter.addItem(arr_tips_date);
```

In your adapter you have to create this method, which adds your data item to its internal adapter collection and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Then it should work just fine.